# Get number of characters in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, http, content-length

I want to send a content length with a http request. For a normal string, I can use the function strlen(). But how do I using that for an array specially for a multidimensional array in PHP? I've found the following script to extract an array like the var_dump(). But what do I need for the Content-Length?

```
function count_array_chars($array){
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
      if (!is_array($value))
      {
          echo $key ." => ". $value ."\r\n" ;
      }
      else
      {
         echo $key ." => array( \r\n";

         foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2)
         {
             echo "\t". $key2 ." => ". $value2 ."\r\n";
         }

         echo ")";
      }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$data_array = array(
    "end"=>array("dateTime"=>$end),
    "start"=>array("dateTime"=>$start),
    "summary"=>$name
  );
```

Comment: content length of what ? an array or what ?

Comment: For a HTTP-Request. To send data to Google via POST, I must using a Content-Length in the request-header. I've updated my question with an example of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to count the values, you can use this approach:

```
$array = array(
    "1" => "abcd",
    "2" => "xyz"
);

function count_array_chars(array $array)
{
    $charNumber = 0;
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($val) use (&$charNumber)
    {
        $charNumber += strlen($val);
    });
    return $charNumber;
}

print count_array_chars($array);
```

If you also want to count the keys, it looks like that:

```
$array = array(
    "end" => array("dateTime"=>"end"),
    "start" => array("dateTime"=>"start"),
    "summary" => "name"
);

function count_array_chars(array $array)
{
    $charNumber = 0;
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($val, $key) use (&$charNumber)
    {
        $charNumber += strlen($val) + strlen($key);
    });
    return $charNumber;
}

print count_array_chars($array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the request catch it, but I'm not there where I want. I have to create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to send the array as part of an http request, you can prepare it with `http_build_query` and count the `strlen` of the chain returned by `http_build_query`:

```
<?php

$data_array = array(
    "end"=>array("dateTime"=>'end'),
    "start"=>array("dateTime"=>'start'),
    "summary"=>'name'
  );

$http_build_query = http_build_query($data_array);
echo strlen($http_build_query);
```